# Linked List insert after

Tags: java

I am a student just learning Java. I have a big test tomorrow and I am a confused by a certain line of code.

The method, insertAfter, finds the number in the linkedList passed into the method and inserts a new node after the match. I do not understand how

```
 curr.setNext(curr.getNext())
```

will take us to the next Node in the list that potentially could be the number we are looking for. So how does this command iterate us through the linked list?

Does it not make more sense to go curr=curr.getNext()?

Thanks and sorry if this is very simple... I am very confused at the moment

```
// assume firstInList is in the list
public void insertAfter(int firstInList, Node toAdd){
    Node curr = head;

    while( curr.getData() != firstInList ){
        curr.setNext(curr.getNext());
    }

    curr.setNext(toAdd);        
}


   Node class
  {
   int getData() {return data};
   void setData(int data) {this.data =data};
   Node getNext() {return next};
   void setNext(Node next) {this.next = next};
  }
```

}

**Additional Method**
The method is called

```
   public void insertBefoe (Node, inList, Node toAdd)
```

Comment: Where is this piece of code coming from?

Comment: @UmNyobe Notes my prof has given me but has failed to explain why it is written the way it is

Comment: show the class `Node` too. this doesn't look right...

Comment: I need to type it all up.. one second

Comment: When googling `curr.setNext(curr.getNext())` one finds a few pieces of code with `curr.setNext(curr.getNext().getNext())` (not inside  an `insertAfter` method, though. Would you understand it if the latter piece were in the same place?

Comment: @UmNyobe edited! Also please assume head is just the start of the list that is a global variable... Thanks

Comment: @arne.b Sorry but I am not understanding why that code would be used? Thanks

Comment: @Teddy13 Sorry, my bad. Didn't think this through. Your suggestion of `curr=curr.getNext()` is much better. Did you run the code?

Answer (score 1):

It seems pretty clear that the code should read:

```
curr = curr.getNext()
```

instead of

```
curr.setNext(curr.getNext());
```

Additionally, the following is broken:

```
curr.setNext(toAdd);
```

Once this has been executed, the part of the list that follows `firstInList` will be lost.

Comment: That is what I am suggesting NPE. So my professor wrote it wrong? Also can you explain to me why curr.setNext(toAdd) would be wrong? Doesnt it make sense if we use curr= curr.getNext(). Thanks!

Comment: @Teddy13: If this is meant to be working code coming from your professor, I think you need a new professor. As `curr.setNext(toAdd)`, think about what happens to the element that follows `firstInList` in the original list.

Comment: So how would you go about to keeping firstInList? Thanks... will accept

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't look correct.

Where is head coming from? Looks like it will never come out of the while loop, unless the `setNext(..)` somehow also alters the code in `getData()`

Unfortuantly its difficult to help since we don't have the whole picture

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shervin... I have edited my question with the Node class.. perhaps it will be more helpful. Also, I believe head is simply just the start of the list... assume we have that global reference. Thanks

Comment: Yes well, as the code reads now, its broken. It doesn't work. It will be an infinit loop, since getData() will never be equals to firstInList